# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation stretches my image, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, transform

I have an image which shows which way is north on a map. This image is updated by CoreLocation if a new heading is found. It is also placed at the correct position, I use the following code:

```
locateMeView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(([CoreLocationController sharedInstance].heading - 45) * M_PI / 180);
CGRect frame = locateMeView.frame;
CGPoint pos = [MapClass vectorForLocation:[CoreLocationController sharedInstance].location mapCenter:curLocation zoom:curZoom];
frame.origin.x = (int)(self.view.bounds.size.width/2 + pos.x - frame.size.width / 2);
frame.origin.y = (int)(self.view.bounds.size.height/2 + pos.y - frame.size.height / 2);
frame.size.width = 24;
frame.size.height = 24;
locateMeView.frame = frame;
```

CoreLocationController is a class which stores the updates of the normal CoreLocation. The MapClass transforms lat/lng coordinates to x/y coordinates on my map. The position of the image is correct, but the rotation is causing strange effects. For 0 en M_PI the image is correct but between these the image is stretched as if it is also rotated around the z-axis and at M_PI/2 and 3 * M_PI/2, it disappears altogether. Can someone explain what is happening and what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found out what was wrong (more or less anyway). When using the transform property you are not allowed (for whatever reason) to change the position by changing the frame, you have to use the center property. So the code in the end was:

```
CGPoint pos = [MapClass vectorForLocation:[CoreLocationController sharedInstance].location mapCenter:curLocation zoom:curZoom];
locateMeView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(([CoreLocationController sharedInstance].heading - 45) * M_PI / 180);
locateMeView.center = CGPointMake(int)(self.view.bounds.size.width/2 + pos.x), (int)(self.view.bounds.size.height/2 + pos.y));
```

Hope that someone with the same problem will find my answer.

Comment: As described [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/demystifying-cgaffinetransform.html), you can also use the `bounds` property.

Comment: Unfortunately this distortion still occurs even if you're not changing the frame or position.

Comment: @Oscar: Setting the `ContentMode` to `UIViewContentMode.Center` may solve your problem.

Comment: +1, This answer gave me enough hint that I remembered to just turn off Auto-Layout in the top-level view.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Another solution:

1. Set transform to identity
2. Change the frame
3. Set transform

In your situation it should be:

```
locateMeView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

CGRect frame = locateMeView.frame;
CGPoint pos = [MapClass vectorForLocation:[CoreLocationController sharedInstance].location mapCenter:curLocation zoom:curZoom];
frame.origin.x = (int)(self.view.bounds.size.width/2 + pos.x - frame.size.width / 2);
frame.origin.y = (int)(self.view.bounds.size.height/2 + pos.y - frame.size.height / 2);
frame.size.width = 24;
frame.size.height = 24;
locateMeView.frame = frame;

locateMeView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(([CoreLocationController sharedInstance].heading - 45) * M_PI / 180);
```

Comment: Excellent advice to set the transform at the identity at the beginning.  This is particularly useful if you're setting the transform in -layoutSubviews and your layoutSubviews is getting called twice.

Comment: just adding this one line fixed my issue locateMeView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; thx

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the transform after the resizing? Order can matter with transforms.

Comment: I tried all different orders, but as you can see after another few hours I found the solution.

Comment: Good on you! Thanks for sharing it.